# Automatically refreshing chunks of data when an update is done with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, design-patterns

I have only one page with distinct sections managed with AJAX.
In one section (1) I add and edit company names.
In the following section (2) I display these company names. (Please see attachment)
When I have edited a company name in section 1 (already coded) the new company name should be updated in the section 2.

[image]

Is there any AJAX **pattern or strategy** to achieve this? I use jQuery and PHP...
THX.-

Comment: jQuery and PHP is fine already IMHO. Just write it. If you run into problems, post your code.

Comment: Assign an attribute to the value `tr->td` then on ajax success update that value.

Comment: This is only an example of the issue. The sections to update are too many and I am afraid to end with a huge spaghetti code. Sure that this it is a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using the **Publisher/Subscriber** design pattern that I want to share.

I show it with an example, similar to that I asked in this question:

1.- Update data via AJAX:

```
$.post(window.location.href,
{
    action : 'update_product'
},
function(output) {
    if ( output.result === true ) {
        $.publish("/product/updated",
                {
                    new_name : output.new_name
                });
    }
}, 'json');
```

2.- Refresh data in another part of the page:

```
$.subscribe("/product/updated", function(e, data) {
    $("#product_name").html(data.new_name);
});
```

That's all. This technique is very fun to code and enjoyed by the users...

---

Tool used: [jQuery Tiny Pub/Sub: A really, really, REALLY tiny pub/sub implementation for jQuery.](https://gist.github.com/661855)
+Info: A nice introduction from *Rebecca Murphey* in "[Loose Coupling with the pubsub Plugin](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/loose-coupling-with-the-pubsub-plugin/)"

Answer (score 0):

Pattern is something like this where you pass a success function that uses the returned results.:

```
$.post('your_update_company_url', function(data) {
    $('.company_name').text(data.company_name);
});
```

Comment: I know to do that. I am asking for an **automatic** way to update several chunks of data...